# Rails Flash message array not parsing with recommended approach on SO

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There are a few questions about parsing the FLASH message built into Rails - everyone says it should be similar to this:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div id="flash_message" class="alert alert-<%= key %>">
        <%= value %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

This prints the message just fine and I have a jQuery fadeout function that works ok.

PROBLEM - what happens when I want to put multiple messages into the flash array?

```
 flash[:success] = ["Job edited successfully"]
else
  addNewJob(params,@cust)   
      flash[:added] = "Job Added Successfully" 
end
if upd
  flash[:success] << "Customer Info Edited Successfully"
else
  flash[:error] = "ERROR: Customer info could not be edited!"
end
```

Here I'm pushing two elements into flash[:success] - and according to other posts on SO and elsewhere, this is fine, because flash.each should pull them out of the array.

But it doesn't:

```
<div id="flash_message" class="alert alert-success">
        ["Job edited successfully", "Customer Info Edited Successfully"]
    </div>
```

This is the page source output, and it looks just like that on the page - shows the whole array as a string of sorts and then fades the whole thing.

What I expected:

Job edited successfully
Customer Info Edited Successfully

On two lines, both fade at the same time.

Help?

Comment: do `value.join("\n")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the template to:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <% Array.new(value).each do |elem| %>
        <div id="flash_message" class="alert alert-<%= key %>">
            <%= elem %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You don't have to say `Array.new(value)`, it would work simply as `Array(value)`.   For those unfamiliar with the convention, that ensures that the result is an array.

Comment: @Ju Liu, this is outside the context of this problem but want to point out that `id`s should be unique.  With your solution you can have multiple `div`s with same `id` i.e. `flash_message`

Comment: @DGM Yeah, I think it's a personal preference more than anything :)

Comment: @vinodadhikary you're right, I maintained as much the original template. Even before, if you had multiple types of flash messages, you could have multiple divs with the same id.

Comment: Ju Liu correct answer, but I solve the multi id issue by just putting the div above the Array.new statement - I actually *want* these messages to print inside a single div so jQuery and fade the whole thing after a couple seconds.  Thanks!